# Proper on implementing incremental values

Tags: reactjs

Now I know the title may be a bit vague so let me help you by explaining my current situation:

I have an array worth of 100 object, which in turn contain a number between 0 and 1. I want to loop through the array and calculate the total amount e.g (1 + 1 = 2).

Currently using .map to go through every object and calaculate the total. When I am counting up using the useState hook, it kinda works. My other approach was using a Let variabele and counting up like this. Although this is way to heavy for the browser.

I want to render the number in between the counts.

```
const[acousticness, setAcousticness] = useState(0);
  let ids = [];

  ids.length == 0 && tracks.items.map((track) => {
    ids.push(track.track.id);
  });

  getAudioFeatures(ids).then((results) => {
    results.map((item) => {
      setAcousticness(acousticness + item.acousticness)
    })
  }) 

  return (
    <div>
      Mood variabele: {acousticness}
    </div>
  )
```

What is the proper way on doing this?

Comment: This code is a mess. You are using 'map' improperly, map should be used when creating a new array based off an old array with the same length. Secondly, keep in mind that you will be setting and resetting state as fast as the browser can run the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is roughly what you are after:

```
import {useMemo, useEffect, useState} from 'react';

const MiscComponent = ({ tracks }) => {
    // Create state variable / setter to store acousticness
    const [acousticness, setAcousticness] = useState(0);

    // Get list of ids from tracks, use `useMemo` so that it does not recalculate the
    // set of ids on every render and instead only updates when `tracks` reference
    // changes.
    const ids = useMemo(() => {
        // map to list of ids or empty array if `tracks` or `tracks.items` is undefined
        // or null.
        return tracks?.items?.map(x => x.track.id) ?? [];
    }, [tracks]);

    // load audio features within a `useEffect` to ensure data is only retrieved when
    // the reference of `ids` is changed (and not on every render).
    useEffect(() => {
        // create function to use async/await instead of promise syntax (preference)
        const loadData = async () => {
            // get data from async function (api call, etc).
            const result = await getAudioFeatures(ids);

            // calculate sum of acousticness and assign to state variable.
            setAcousticness(result?.reduce((a, b) => a + (b?.acousticness ?? 0), 0) ?? 0)
        };

        // run async function.
        loadData();
    }, [ids, setAcousticness])

    // render view.
    return (
        <div>
            Mood variabele: {acousticness}
        </div>
    )
}
```